# I can't create click event on code, i need to find element for it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<button type="button" class="btn _modal" data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-target="#request_demo" xpath="1">Products demo</button>
```

i can't click on this element in my selenium script, please help me

`driver.findElement(By.className("btn _modal")).click();`

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn\ _modal"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have a space

If you look at the error message you see:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":**".btn\ _modal"**}

Note the slash that's been added to the selector. The element is actually two classes applied to one element; "btn" and "_modal". The `By.classname()` will only except a single name so it's trying to put them together and obviously failing.

The best way to handle it would be use `By.cssSelector()` and use dot notation:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn._modal")).click();
```